# How to make exoplayer to adaptively changing quality?

Tags: android, kotlin, video-streaming, exoplayer, android-media3

I want make ExoPlayer if the internet speed is good to play high resolution vice versa to play in low resolution. I also used bandwitmether with default or custom initial bandwith estimate and AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory. How can fix it to play only specified internet quality, because defaultBandwithmeter gives false bitrate. Thanks in advance

```
  val trackSelector : DefaultTrackSelector = DefaultTrackSelector(context

    ).apply {
        setParameters(buildUponParameters().setAllowMultipleAdaptiveSelections(true).setForceHighestSupportedBitrate(false).setForceLowestBitrate(false))
    }


    private val simpleCache: SimpleCache = MyApp.simpleCache


    val loadControl: LoadControl = DefaultLoadControl.Builder()
        .setAllocator(DefaultAllocator(true, 16))
        .setBufferDurationsMs(
            MIN_BUFFER_DURATION,
            MAX_BUFFER_DURATION,
            MIN_PLAYBACK_START_BUFFER,
            MIN_PLAYBACK_RESUME_BUFFER
        )

        .build()




    init {





        val b2 = context.resources.configuration.locale.country

        Log.e("vag", b2.toString())

        httpDataSourceFactory = DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory()
            .setAllowCrossProtocolRedirects(true)

        defaultDataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSource.Factory(
            context, httpDataSourceFactory
        )
        cacheDataSourceFactory = CacheDataSource.Factory()
            .setCache(simpleCache)


            .setUpstreamDataSourceFactory(httpDataSourceFactory)
            .setFlags(CacheDataSource.FLAG_IGNORE_CACHE_ON_ERROR)


        bindingVideos.masterExoPlayer.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_ZOOM);

        currentExoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(context).setLoadControl(loadControl).setTrackSelector(trackSelector)
            .build()
        bindingVideos.masterExoPlayer.player = currentExoPlayer



    }
```